# Closing old questions which have answers?

Tags: discussion

In my close review queue just appeared a question which I would usually migrate to Superuser but that was not possible because it was old. To tell the truth: I am not sure what closing means exactly. Would the question not appear in search results any more? Is a question that has been around for years with answers going to cause problems if it is not closed? I assume it got some attention because a high rep user just added another answer.

[Starting Apache service “requested operation has failed”](https://serverfault.com/questions/109650/starting-apache-service-requested-operation-has-failed)

Comment: Which question in particular?

Comment: @TomO'Connor edited

Comment: Closed questions certainly *do* appear in search results. Coincidentally, I landed on a closed SO question just yesterday evening.

Answer (score 4):

Closing a question disallows new answers. If neither the question nor answer have upvotes (not sure of the exact number) it will get deleted after a while (not sure on the timing).

While a question is close it is still indexed by Google and other search engines.

I answered that question as it has attracted over 1k search hits, and didn't have an actual answer to the question. I agree the question is somewhat off-topic, but it's also a search magnet.

Comment: I believe the auto-delete rules are still "> 30 days old, closed as something other than a duplicate, negative score, no answers"

Comment: How did you know it had attracted so many hits?  So you have some special mod power that lets you find those?

Comment: @Zoredache I could tell you, but then I'd have to kill you. =]

Answer (score 2):

That question is unanswered by our strict definition. To be `answered` a question has to have *upvoted answers*.

I would guess that it has been languishing in the database and the [community](https://serverfault.com/users/-1/community) user pushed it to the front page to get more eyes on it. This has worked as it has an edit, a new answer and some close votes.

I don't know if the edit adding [wamp](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/wamp) came before the close votes but with it it's knda off topic as wamp isn't really topical here.

For me it' more NARQ and unanswerable as there isn't really much information to go on and the OP's account is deleted.

Comment: ChrisS dropped the tag on it today. It's definitely NARQ material though.

Comment: @Adrian: I know - that's why I said `I don't know if ...`

Comment: Ah, that's my bad.